# How to use 7-zip to send a Zip64-compressed file to standard output?

Tags: compression

I would like to make a Zip64 archive from a bunch of `bzip2` files, using `7za`'s `-so` option to send the compressed archive to standard output:

```
$ 7za a dummy -tzip -so myFiles*.bz2 > test.zip
```

Here is the output I get:

```
7-Zip (A) [64] 9.13 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-04-15
p7zip Version 9.13 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
Scanning

Creating archive stdout

System error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
E_NOINTERFACE
```

The file `test.zip` is empty. There is no information in the documentation about the error `E_NOINTERFACE`. What can I do within the application to fix this? Thanks for your advice!

**EDIT**

I do not want to extract `bz2` files to standard output. I want to (a)dd to an archive called `test.zip`, made from a set of `bz2` files, by sending the bundled archive to standard output. This is to use `7za` to archive `bz2` files in a manner similar to `tar`, as `zip` files provide random access while `tar` archives do not.

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately, it looks like [the developer confirms](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/forums/forum/45797/topic/3874921) that 7-Zip does not support writing to standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `-so`, of the arguments to the `-t` option, I was only able to get `gzip`,  `bzip2` and `tar` to work. I get `E_NOINTERFACE` with `zip` as you do and I get `E_NOTIMPL` with `7z`.

I was not able to find a fix or workaround. This may be a bug in the beta version, but I had similar behavior from both the Linux version 9.04 beta and the Windows command line version 4.65.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Perhaps there is a bug in 7-Zip?

Comment: zip is not supported as docs say: http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/stdin.htm

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to extract files from the bzip2 files first, or just to include all the bzip files in a 7-zip archive?  The -so switch *extracts* to standard output, so you'd need to run it through 7-zip again to add it to a new archive.

Try something like:

`7za e -so myFiles*.bz2  | 7za a -tzip - test.zip`